# setType of Intent which does not include images and videos but everything else

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to search user's phone for files so i am using `intent.setType`. I am little confused. I don't want to search for video and images,but i want to search for all other files like `pdf`,text,`docx` etc.What should i write in `intent,setType("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this you can specify your `intent.setType` like this

```
intent.setType("application/x-excel|application/pdf|text/plain");
```

Comment: Need to have an File Explorer app

Answer (score 1):

Try below code;

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("*/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: I did intent.setType("*/*"); but it only shows images and videos file